# Text to MP3 program

Tags: speech-synthesis

I'm looking for a program that quickly converts a passage of text to speech and delivers in MP3 format. (Other audio formats may be fine too.)

There are a bunch of websites that do this, but they're either pretty slow (you have to wait for them to process it, which can take minutes, then click download) or have a word/character limit.

I was wondering if there's a simple lightweight program that does this. (I'm using Windows 10 if that matters.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Balabolka](http://www.cross-plus-a.com/balabolka.htm) is free and can save as MP3. It's free and runs on Windows. It's even available as a portable version. It will detect the installed voices.

Since both, the program and the voices are available on your PC, you'll not need an Internet connection and it's fast.

[image: Balabolka screenshot]

There are various [voices](https://sites.fastspring.com/nextup/product/nuance?store=parameters) available for 45 USD. I am happy with the Nuance voices.

Answer (score 1):

[TextAloud](http://nextup.com/purchase.html) is a commercial tool for ~ 30 USD. It's an application that you install on your PC and it will use voices from your PC, so it works offline. I own a very old version that cannot save in MP3 format (just WAV). However, there are [tutorials](http://www.openu.ac.il/ld/download/document_MP3.pdf) available that give instructions on how to save as MP3, so I guess they added that feature.

There are various [voices](https://sites.fastspring.com/nextup/product/nuance?store=parameters) available for 45 USD. I am happy with the Nuance voices.